# Accessing socket.io scope from outer scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a scenario where user sends a POST request, in express I set up a route, get the post data, validate it, store it in db then I need to broadcast it to all sockets connected. But since the socket variable is available inside `io.sockets.on('connection')` I might be able to access the inner scope of it with a closure this way:

```
Var a = {}; //global
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
    a.inner = function(data){
        socket.broadcast.emit('boo',data)
    }
}
```

Then call `a.inner(data)`

Is this normal? is there a better way to access or call inner functions ?

Thanks

Comment: The above doesn't work . The socket a.inner calls may not be the socket im expecting .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use this:

```
var userIdSocketMapper = {};
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  var userId = socket.handshake.userId;
  userIdSocketMapper[userId] = socket;
});

app.post('/:userId', function(req, res) {
   var socket = userIdSocketMapper[req.params.userId];
   if (socket) {
     socket.broadcast.emit('boo', data);
   }
});
```

Comment: As the users grow, the userIdSocketMapper gets large and is also unnecessary storage , and also socket objects dont get gc'ed even if the client disconnects due to reference . But a good idea